# Юзер должен ввести массив через окно prompt

Tags: javascript

Такое задание! "Составить алгоритм: на входе есть числовой массив, необходимо вывести элементы массива кратные 3"
Но не могу сделать,что бы пользователь сам вводил числа в  окне которое откроется через prompt,а программа высчитывала какие делиться на 3. Помогите, чего не хватает в коде?

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let newArray = [];
for(i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++)
   if (array[i] % 3 == 0) { 
    newArray.push(array[i]);
    } alert(newArray);
```

Comment: в коде не хватает `prompt`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = prompt('Введите массив через пробел :'), arrayResult = [];
array = array.trim().split(/\s+/);

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] % 3 == 0 && array[i] != 0) arrayResult.push(array[i]);
}

alert('Ваш массив :\n' + array + '\n \n' + 'Числа которые делиться на 3 :\n' + arrayResult);
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, всё работает!)